# How to load dynamic values in select options in the fieldconfig in dynamic form

Tags: angular

type: "select",
label: "Country",
name: "country",
value: "UK",
options: ["India", "UAE", "UK", "US"] ----is static
I want to load options dynamically.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `*ngFor` function where you can specify your array. E.g.:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of options">{{ item }}</option>
```

`ngFor` in this case works similarly than a foreach loop.

Comment: I want to load dynamically from service

Comment: At this point I can not understand what you really want to do. There is just one line written and from that line I could gess only one solution. Can you edit your question more specifically please?

Answer (score 0):

Load your dynamic values to options array
(**res** is the reponse object with dynamic values)

```
this.options = res
```

Then use *ngFor in html to set dynamic values to options in `<select></select>`

```
<option *ngFor="let val of options">{{ val }}</option>
```

Comment: I created dynamic fields in constants file. In that form elements field config drop down fields I added options:[]. For that options I am loading options values in components.ts file using element.options. When debugging values are coming. But when form loading only empty spaces are loading. How to solve that.